# What is the difference between given() and with() in Rest Assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

```
 RequestSpecification request1 = RestAssured.given();
        // Setting Base URI
        request1.baseUri("https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com");
        // Setting Base Path
        request1.basePath("/booking");

        // Creating request specification using with()
        RequestSpecification request2 = RestAssured.with();
        // Setting Base URI
        request2.baseUri("https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com");
        // Setting Base Path
        request2.basePath("/ping");
```

As here we are using both what is the difference amongst two?

Answer (score 0):

Methods: "and", "with", "when", "given", "that" and "request" are synctatic sugar for RequestSpecification and you don't need them to create RequestSpecification object.

Comment: Do they serve same purpose or depending on its usage purpose varies?

Answer (score 0):

The package com.jayway.restassured indicates that `with()` and `given()` do the same thing.

```
public static RequestSpecification with() {
   return given();
}
```